# Cannot get Apache POI for my Excel reading to work

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, deprecation-warning

I am trying to use this basic layout for a  program that can read an Excel file. I want to expand beyond just this code but for some reason every time I build the code, I get an error "Note: C:\Users\Ryan Kabir\Documents\NetBeansProjects\ExcelReader\src\excelreader\ExcelReader.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details." I tried compiling with javac -Xlint:deprecation ExcelReader.java but I couldn't find out which method is deprecated. 
Right not my test excel file is just a 3x6 table.

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
 
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
 
/**
 * A dirty simple program that reads an Excel file.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class ExcelReader {
     
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFilePath = "Books.xlsx";
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));
         
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();
         
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
             
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                 
                switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                        System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                        break;
                    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                        System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                        break;
                }
                System.out.print(" - ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
         
        workbook.close();
        inputStream.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What version of `apache-poi` are you using? post your dependencies

Comment: That is not an error, it's a warning. That is not the cause of what isn't working, which you did not specify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cell.getCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType()) as well as all the fields in [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) are deprecated. Use [Cell.getCellTypeEnum](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellTypeEnum()) and [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html) instead as shown in [Getting the cell contents](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Getting+the+cell+contents).

It needs to be a little bit changed because of the

```
error: an enum switch case label must be the unqualified name of an enumeration constant
     case CellType.STRING:
```

But the following should work:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
...
            switch (cell.getCellTypeEnum()) { //up to apache poi version 3.17
            //switch (cell.getCellType()) { //using apache poi version 4.0.0 upwards

                case STRING:
                    System.out.println(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                    break;
                case NUMERIC:
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                        System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    }
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue());
                    break;
                case FORMULA:
                    System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula());
                    break;
                case BLANK:
                    System.out.println();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println();
            }
...
```

It is always good to read the [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html).

---

From `apache poi` version `4.0.0` upwards now [Cell.getCellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getCellType--) returns [CellType](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/CellType.html). So using those versions we need using this method now.